# Unable to Refund Excess Ether to Users on Remix and Metamask

Tags: ethereum, solidity, metamask

Building a crowdfunding application. Once the target is met, any ether contribution to the project will be refunded back via msg.sender.transfer(excess) or msg.sender.send(excess).

Tested extensively on Remix and Metamask (Deployed via Web3). Key issue is excess funds are are fully deducted from sender's accounts and not refunded to the sender.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Funds {
    uint public maximumValue = 100;
    uint public currentValue = 0;

    // addFunds function that takes in amount in ether
    function addFunds (uint _amount) public payable {
        // Converts wei (msg.value) to ether
        require(msg.value / 1000000000000000000 == _amount);
        // if the sum of currentValue and amount is greater than maximum value, refund the excess
        if (currentValue + _amount > maximumValue){
            uint excess = currentValue + _amount - maximumValue;
            currentValue = maximumValue;
            msg.sender.transfer(excess);
        } else {
            currentValue += _amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the values in your contract are in ether, so you probably want `msg.sender.transfer(excess * 1 ether)`. My guess is that the refund is working, but it's sending back such a small amount of wei that you haven't noticed.

IMO, a better fix would be to use wei everywhere:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Funds {
    uint public maximumValue = 100 ether;
    uint public currentValue = 0;

    function addFunds() external payable {
        // if the sum of currentValue and amount is greater than maximum value, refund the excess
        if (currentValue + msg.value > maximumValue){
            uint excess = currentValue + msg.value - maximumValue;
            currentValue = maximumValue;
            msg.sender.transfer(excess);
        } else {
            currentValue += msg.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Refund was working but was sending back an insignificant amount of ether